# How many rational elements are in the multinomial? $(\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[5]{x}+2\sqrt{x})^5$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-theorem, multinomial-theorem

> How many rational elements are in the multinomial?
> $(\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[5]{x}+2\sqrt{x})^5$

According to the multinomial theorem, $\sum_{i+j+k=5}^{}\frac{5!}{i!j!k!}2^k\ x^{\frac{1}{3}i+\frac{1}{5}j+\frac{1}{2}k}$

So I think it's rational when $k \ \in  \  \mathbb{N}$ and $(\frac{1}{3}i+\frac{1}{5}j+\frac{1}{2}k)\ \in  \  \mathbb{N}$ and $i+j+k=5$

Which satisfy only when $i=3,j=0,k=2$ and $j=5,i=k=0$ so if's correct then are only 2 rational elements in the sum iteration?

**Additional question**
Needing to find how many elements are in the multinomial, so what I figured is finding in how many for the equations $a + b + c= 5$ to be formed? which is $D(3,5) = C(3+5-1,5)$ but I am not sure about it

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the analysis in the first part of your query.  There is one ambiguity:

In the case of $i=3,k=2$, this can be regarded as one element or the sum of $\binom{5}{3} = 10$ elements, depending on your interpretation of the word element.

Depending on your interpretation of the word *element*, the second part of your query can be regarded as a [Stars and Bars](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) problem, where you want the number of non-negative integer solutions to

$$i + j + k = 5.$$

The enumeration is

$$\binom{5 + [3-1]}{[3-1]} = \binom{7}{2} = 21.$$

This agrees with the number that you (the OP) computed.

Comment: I specifically set $i=3$ and $k=2$ because I wanted the power of $x$ to be a real number

Comment: @LightLamps Yes, that makes sense.  I was simply pointing out that there is a subtle ambiguity around the term *element*.  For example, when you multiply $(a + b + c)^5$ out manually, you could reasonably infer that there will be $(3^5)$ *elements*.  Alternatively, you could collect common **terms** (e.g. $a^2 \times b^2 \times c$) and infer that these $(30)$ terms combine into $(1)$ *element*.